# Semantic-UI-React Sidebar mini version on collapse

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

Using Semantic-UI-React is it possible to instead of the sidebar disappearing altogether, having it minimize and appear as a smaller version of itself?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not really a "mini" version of the sidebar. You could in theory change a sidebar from the list type sidebar to the icon type if you wanted Which might potentially do what you want. That would still require you overriding or modifying styles a little yourself.